# HTTPS login: Logging will not add app to FB -is normal?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am developing an iframe application and i use https. I use latest SDK. When i access my application first time, instead appearing the permission request, it appears this window.
http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/4125/appfb2.jpg

Is possible to get rid of this window and to display directly permissions request dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove this window...This is the new Facebook permission dialog(announced at F8)

From what I understand in the new permission dialog there are users/friends permissions and extended permissions unlike in the old everything was together.The users/friends permissions appear on the first screen, followed by extended permissions on the 2nd screen.

You can read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/